# Extends template in Twig with Twig_Loader_String

Tags: twig

I have to render a template with Twig_Loader_String and I need to extend a template, like below:

```
$body='{% extends "/views/path/to/my/template" %}
       {% block body %} Hello {% endblock %}';
```

And in PHPs side I wrote:

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->render($body,array());
```

I don't understand why the result after render is just:

```
/views/path/to/my/template
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have a string loader, that very string is your actual template. You're extending it, and overriding the body block - but it has no body block.

Comment: I'm trying to extend /views/path/to/my/template because in that there is a block called body and I want t oreplace the content with "Hello". But it doesn't work, why?

Comment: Then you'll need an environment with both the string and the filesystem loaders. I can't help you with details there, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the answer by @Maerlyn with some code how to do it:

```
$loaders = [
    new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path/to/twig/views'),
    new Twig_Loader_String()
];

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Chain($loaders);

$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```